# Do people still use a [downloader]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Nice useless meta  tag. [downloader](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/downloader) is only a useful tag when people tell you just what downloader they are using.  On its own it serves no purpose.

Only a few questions tagged with it so it's an easy kill.

Comment: Would we consider [text editor](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/text-editors) to be in the same vein as this?

Answer (score 2):

I actually consider it semi-useful. There are quite a few programs and games out there that use either some custom downloader or something rebranded (generally referred to as *downloader*, at least in many communities I know) and they might be hard to identify based on the customization being applied.

However, how about making it a synonym of [download-manager](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/download-manager)? While most *download managers* are more generic and allow you to download several things, *downloaders* are typically just specialized or limited *download managers*.

Comment: Although synonimizing sounds like a good idea, it might give additional confusion to users.

Comment: tags for what the questioner is trying to do might be useful like `download videos` if newbies can find them